# Ecommerce (Spree) print count of products with completed orders on Index page. (postgres)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, e-commerce, spree

On our product gallery page, I'd really like to query the database to find how many of each product has been purchased, and print that number on the page (for admin users only).  I feel like I have all the pieces, I just don't know how to put it together to work.

There is a Products table that is referenced to print out all the products. 
There is an LineItems table (Spree::LineItems >> Spree::Orders) where the product can be called/identified by:

```
@line_items.each do |line_item|
    line_item.product.id
end
```

& this is what defines an order as complete in relation to that line_item:

```
@line_item.order.state == "complete"
```

So...I'd like to see if @product.id and @line_item.product.id match (where the @line_item.order.state == "complete") and count how many.

Basically, we iterate each product on the gallery page, so I want to see for each *product* how many times it appears as a *line_item* in an *order* where the *order.state is complete*

I'm no engineer (as you can obviously tell), but I feel like I'm making this more complicated than it needs to be.  Help?

We're using a Postgres database.  Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

That should give you a count of line items associated at the same time with a product with the given id and an order with 'complete' state.

```
LineItem.joins(:product, :order).where(orders: { state: 'complete' }).where(products: { id: your_product_id }).count
```

No need to iterate! Just a database query (using ActiveRecord), which also is extremely more efficient than iteration.

I assumed your tables are called orders, products (used in the where clauses) and the associations on the LineItem ActiveRecord object are called order, product (used in the join). Otherwise simply replace those values with the appropriate ones.